# Is hibernate-memcached a good approach for Java applications?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, grails, memcached

We are testing memcached as hibernate 2nd level cache in our Grails app.

We have some background using memcached and really like the simplicity and scalability of this tool.

Everything is working fine, but I have a couple of concerns.
First, the hibernate-memcached seems to be abandoned. There is only available an old version and seems that this project was not updated in last year.

Also looks like the performance isn't as good as expected. We made some benchmarks and these are the results:

- No cache: 350 requests/s, System load: 50 (really high)
- Memcached: 600 requests/s, System load: 2
- Ehcache: 1500 requests/s, System load: 9

All the tests were made on same infrastructure with same resources.

In memcached case we observed that there are a lot of tomcat threads in blocking state (when using read-write strategy) or in waiting state (nonstrict-read-write).

Because of these facts, and also a lack of updated information, I'm asking if hibernate memcached is a good way to go ? In majority of huge projects and platforms that we see online, memcached is used but seems that in Java world (at least with Hibernate) is not the best option.

What are your opinions ?

Thanks for helping.